# Ruby on Rails + MongoDB and MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have created a sample DB with MongoDB with data from a JSON file on mongodbs website
I have imported it with the following command.
mongoimport --db test --collection zips --file zips.json
The data is being processed and when I try to search for data in the console it will show up, so far so good.

My problem is when I'm trying to use the DB with my Rails app. I have created a Class, City, the code looks like this.

```
    class City
       include Mongoid::Document
       field :c, as: :city, type: String
       field :l, as: :loc, type: Array
       field :p, as: :population, type: Integer
       field :s, as: :state, type: String
       field :_id, type: Integer
    end
```

And my mongoid.yml file looks like this

```
    development:
     # Configure available database sessions. (required)
    sessions:
     # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
     # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
     # (required).
    database: exjobb
     # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
     # of host:port pairs. (required)
    hosts:
      - localhost:27017
    options:

    options:

    test:
     sessions:
      default:
       database: exjobb
       hosts:
        - localhost:27017
       options:
       consistency: :strong
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Activerecord is disabled. When Im starting rails console and try City.where...
I get the following output.

```
    City.where(city: "Acmar")
    => #<Mongoid::Criteria
    selector: {"c"=>"Acmar"}
    options:  {}
    class:    City
    embedded: false>
```

And if I try City.first an error is thrown

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:409:in `__evaluate__'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:357:in `__database_name__'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:198:in `database_name'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:429:in `current_database_name'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:228:in `mongo_session'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:171:in `collection'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:256:in `initialize'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:48:in `new'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:48:in `create_context'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:31:in `context'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:21:in `rescue in first'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:19:in `first'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/finders.rb:117:in `first'
from (irb):1
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-    3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

I've uploaded my code [here](https://github.com/josefottosson/exjobb), please clone and try to help me, im stuck.
As you can see, my db is not empty. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bho2H.png

Comment: Why do you use the store_in ?

Comment: Oh, I've removed that, it was from a tutorial. Now I Get "nil" as an answer. But I KNOW that there's data in the db, it works when I use the mongo console..

Comment: Do City.count and City.all.to_a and paste back the result :-)

Comment: City.count = 0, City.all.to_a = [] I dont understand, where do I connect to the database? I thought MongoID did that for me?

Comment: Then the city collection is empty mate

Comment: No. Look at this image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bho2H.png

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database?

Comment: Yes, localhost and name of db is 'exjobb'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid (using similar mapping conventions to ActiveRecord) pluralizes the class name to get the collection name. It looks like you have a collection called `city` but Mongoid will have mapped your class to a collection called `cities`.

You can override the collection name:

```
class City
  store_in collection: "city"
end
```

or better still import your data into a cities collection.

Comment: My collection is named "city". When using Mongodb console, I can write db.city.findOne, I cant write db.cities.findOne. Are u sure this is the problem?

Comment: Yes I think so. Mongoid is looking for a collection called cities. If you don't want to change the database then it should be easy to try to add the `store_in` declaration to your model.

Comment: It solved it, thank you very much :)
I used the store_in in my code before, but it was named "City", not "city" ;) Cheers!